# OpenCV - get Rtrees values doesn't work - CopyTo type mismatch

Tags: c++, opencv, random-forest, opencv3.0

I'm trying to access `RTrees`'s nodes and trees. Having the following code:

```
Ptr<Rtrees> rt = RTrees::create();
...
...
rt->train(data);
vector<DTrees::Split> splits = rt->getSplits();
```

I keep getting the memory access violation. Note that `rt->getSplits()` works by itself and I guess the problem is with the data type of `splits`.

Also, when I read training data information and want to copy it into a variable:

```
std::vector<int> catMap;
 data->getCapMap().copyTo(catMap);
```

it copies garbage into the `carMap` and I have to copy it element by element instead of using `copyTo` method. 
Do you have any idea about these two questions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

That memory error does not look like caused by the data type and the type of splits is correct. If you're doubting it, use 'auto'

```
auto splits = rt->getSplits();
```

Try out other functions to see if your RTrees model is actually available,

```
auto roots = model.getRoots();
auto nodes = model.getNodes();
```

Set a debug point or print log message to see if they are empty if there're no memory access error at run time

```
std::cout << "num trees " << roots.size();
std::cout << "num nodes " <<  nodes.size();
```